# Como fazer um item de lista mostrar/ocultar uma DIV quando clicado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```css
#fonte {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: dotted;
  }

#conteudo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 210px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: dotted;
  }

.source li {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  outline: dotted;
  padding: 5px
  }


.item li {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: block;
  outline: dotted;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div id="fonte">
  <ul class="source">
    <li> EMPRESA 1 </li>
    <li> EMPRESA 2 </li>
    <li> EMPRESA 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="conteudo">
  <ul class="item" id=emp1>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
    <li> 3 </li>
  </ul>
  
    <ul class="item" id=emp2>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
  </ul>
  
      <ul class="item" id=emp3>
    <li> 1 </li>
    <li> 2 </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Conseguiste resolver esta pergunta?

Answer (score 1):

A maneira mais correta de fazer isso é usando uma classe de CSS.
E neste caso simples nem é preciso jQuery.

Podes iterar esses elementos e adicionar-lhes um oscultador de eventos. Na altura de iterar os elementos é importante guardar o *index* desse elemento, pois a cada `#fonte li` corresponde um `ul.item`. Daí ter usado `var index = j;` no exemplo em baixo. Assim, criando um novo escopo, guardo esse index para mais tarde ser usado.

**Mudanças no CSS:**

```
#conteudo ul {
    position: absolute; /* opcional */
    top: 0px; /* opcional */
    transition: opacity .8s;
    opacity: 0;
}
.open {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
(function () { // criar um escopo próprio para não exportar variáveis para o espaço global
    var fontes = document.querySelectorAll('#fonte .source li');
    var conteudos = document.querySelectorAll('ul.item');
    for (var j = 0; j < fontes.length; j++) { // percorrer as fontes 
        (function () { // criar novo escopo para guardar em memória as variáveis declaradas aqui dentro
            var index = j; // para saber qual o index do elemento clicado
            fontes[j].addEventListener('click', function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < conteudos.length; i++) {
                    conteudos[i].classList.remove('open');
                }
                conteudos[index].classList.add('open'); 
            });
        })();
    }
})();
```

```js
(function () {
    var fontes = document.querySelectorAll('#fonte .source li');
    var conteudos = document.querySelectorAll('ul.item');
    for (var j = 0; j < fontes.length; j++) {
        (function () {
            var index = j;
            fontes[j].addEventListener('click', function () {
                for (var i = 0; i < conteudos.length; i++) {
                    conteudos[i].classList.remove('open');
                }
                conteudos[index].classList.add('open');
            });

        })();
    }



})()
```

```css
#fonte {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: dotted;
}
#conteudo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 210px;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: dotted;
}
.source li {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  outline: dotted;
  padding: 5px
}
.item li {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  display: block;
  outline: dotted;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
}
#conteudo ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transition: opacity .8s;
  opacity: 0;
}
.open {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="fonte">
    <ul class="source">
        <li>EMPRESA 1</li>
        <li>EMPRESA 2</li>
        <li>EMPRESA 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="conteudo">
    <ul class="item" id=emp1>
        <li>E1, li 1</li>
        <li>E1, li 2</li>
        <li>E1, li 3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="item" id=emp2>
        <li>E2 li 1</li>
        <li>E2, li 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="item" id=emp3>
        <li>E3, li 1</li>
        <li>E3, li 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5rktbn3/

Comment: Obrigado Sergio, ajudou muito... só tem um problema agora... nessa mesma página tem um campo de pesquisa que agora não funciona mais.

Comment: @RafaelBitencourt não estou a ver de que maneira o meu código pode influênciar outras partes da página... podes usar o meu jsFiddle e adptar até conseguires mostrar esse problema?

Comment: Fiz a atualização... Se puder dar uma olhada agradeço.

Comment: @RafaelBitencourt fizeste atualização onde?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/download/sz2d725g5bzzwz8/DA.zip

Comment: Segue o link no comentario anterior. Esse projeto tem uma importância pra mim então estou disposto a negociar em dindin, se estiver afim.

Comment: @RafaelBitencourt obrigado pela confiança mas não tenho tempo para aceitar trabalho. Qual é o ficheiro HTML que estás a usar desse link que mandas-te? Qual é o erro que te aparece na consola?

Comment: Cara, não quero que faça tudo pra mim, só preciso que este campo funcione... É essencial. O resto eu me viro... Pode ser? Salvei tudo em zip por que fica melhor para você visualizar como as tags estão estruturadas.

Comment: O que aparece no console é "Can't find variable list". 

Este é o script que estou usando: 
var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'ref', 'empresa', 'tags', ]
};

var userList = new List('conteudo', options);

Comment: @RafaelBitencourt eu vi o zip e daí a minha pergunta: Qual é o ficheiro HTML que estás a usar desse link que mandas-te?

Comment: Untitled 2. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simplesmente criar uma função do tipo

```
function esconderDiv(qual) {
    document.getElementById(qual).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

E chama-la com um onclick, diretamente

```
<div id="fonte">
  <ul class="source">
    <li onclick="esconderDiv('fonte')"> EMPRESA 1 </li>
    <li> EMPRESA 2 </li>
    <li> EMPRESA 3 </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes fazer isso utilizando o [**`slideToggle()`**](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/) do jQuery.
Por exemplo:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".mostrar").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```css
.mostrar{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 75px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">Mostrar</button>
<div class="mostrar">Olá!</div>
```

Aqui tens também um exemplo no jsFiddle com o código da tua pergunta, que irá fazer com que apenas as `<li>` que têm o `número 1`, `número 2`, ou `número 3` sejam apresentadas na caixinha do lado direito ► **http://jsfiddle.net/aqbq7u4a/**

Answer (score 0):

Com jQuery:

```
var lista = $("#conteudo ul");

lista.click(function() {
    var indiceDoItem = lista.index(this);

    // Oculta ou mostra a empresa correspondente.
    $(".source li").eq(indiceDoItem).toogle();
});
```